# Matrix multiplication explanation

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

When we multiply two matrices A of size m x k and B of size k x n we use the following code:

```
  #for resultant matrix rows
  for i in range(m):
    #for resultant matrix column
    for j in range(n):
      for l in range(k):
        #A's row x B's columns
        c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][l]*b[l][j]
```

are my comments in the code right explanation of the loops? Is there a better explanation of the loops or is there a better thought process to code matrix multiplication?

EDIT1: I am not looking for a better code. My question is about the thought process that goes in when we transform the math of matrix multiplicate into code.

Comment: If you want another suggestion for the comment, then "A's ith row x B's jth column"?

Comment: also you probably shouldn't use `l` as an iteration variable, it looks like `1` or `I` at first glance

Comment: Your code is correct. I am using a similar loop (look at the javascript on this page : https://math.tools/calculator/matrix/multiplication/ ) for one my projects. I would love to add a detailed explanation like you asked to the page. Some of the explanations below are decent but I still feel we could do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but if you want to add detail comment/explanation like you ask for you can do so:

```
 #for resultant matrix rows
  for i in range(m):
    #for resultant matrix column
    for j in range(n):
      #for each entry in resultant matrix we have k entries to sum
      for l in range(k):
        #where each i, j entry in the result matrix is given by multiplying the 
        #entries A[i][l] (across row i of A) by the entries B[l][j] (down 
        #column j of B), for l = 1, 2, ..., k, and summing the results over l:
        c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][l]*b[l][j]
```

EDIT: if you want a better explanation of the loop or thought process than take out `#A's row x B's columns` comments.  and replace it with "where each i, j entry in the result matrix is given by multiplying the entries A[i][l] (across row i of A) by the entries B[l][j] (down column j of B), for l = 1, 2, ..., k, and summing the results over " also don't use `l` as an iterator it looks like a `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.dot` function. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). Example (extracted from the documentatio):

```
> a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
> b = [[4, 1], [2, 2]]
> np.dot(a, b)
> array([[4, 1],
        [2, 2]])
```

Comment: The documentation states:

_Dot product of two arrays. For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication..._

Comment: Sorry my mistake, Regardless, the question is about documentation of his or her code, not looking for an existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The condition that should always stand in order to do 2 matrices multiplication is that first `matrix` must have the same amount of `rows` that the other `matrix` has `columns`.

so if `matrix_1` is `m x n` than second `matrix_2` should be `n x p`. The result of the two will have a dimension of `m x p`

the [Pseudocode](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) will be:

```
multiplyMatrix(matrix1, matrix2)

-- Multiplies rows and columns and sums them
  multiplyRowAndColumn(row, column) returns number
  var
    total: number
  begin
    for each rval in row and cval in column
    begin
       total += rval*cval
    end
    return total
  end

begin

-- If the rows don't match up then the function fails

  if matrix1:n != matrix2:m  return failure;

  dim    = matrix1:n   -- Could also be matrix2:m
  newmat = new squarematrix(dim)  -- Create a new dim x dim matrix
  for each r in matrix1:rows and c in matrix2:columns
  begin

  end
end
```

In python either you can do what you did, or you can use `ijk-algo`, `ikj-algo`, `psyco ikj-algo`, `Numpy`, or `SciPy` to accomplish this. It appears that Numpy is the fastest and most efficient.

YOUR CODE LOOKS RIGHT AND YOUR COMMENTS ALSO DO LOOK CORRECT